# How to access a .dat file in the same folder as a .jar file from within the .jar file?

Tags: java, file-io, executable-jar

I need to read and write to a .dat file to save high scores for a game I'm working on. It all works in Eclipse, but when I convert it to a runnable `.jar` file there's no `.dat` file to save my scores to. How would I access a `.dat` file that is in the same folder as my `.jar` file from my `.jar` file to save my scores?

Comment: Did you try copying the .dat to the directory where the jar is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is a very bad idea to attempt to write to the location from which the jar file is running.  What happens if the jar file is running from inside a .war file as a web application? In that case you cannot write to the jar file's location.

You should modify the program to look at either an environment variable, a java .properties file or a comand-line argument (or all 3) to tell it where to write the output, and then provide a suitable output location when executing.